# How can i remove <eof> characters in a text document

Tags: eof

I am getting a error "Unexpected token "< eof >" "--- when I am running a query against a java based xquery library

So I would like to remove the < eof> characters-- how do I remove those? I am working on a Windows 7 PC

Comment: `<eof>` likely stands for *end of file*. You're missing expected tokens (e.g. close parentheses matching open ones).

Comment: Please give more details about what you're querying, where you're querying from, etc. Also, if you're programming, your question might be better suited for [SO] …

Answer (score 1):

It's not a character. The parser is telling you that you reached the End Of File (EOF) but that it expected something else instead.

Comment: the problem i have is the same as this -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095328/saxon-unexpected-token-e-o-f   -- which means there is more than 1 EOF in my text file(that contains the query)-- but how do I find and remove the extra EOF? Thanks...

Comment: Either you really have the string `"<eof>"` in your input (just check with an editor) or as I expect you are reaching the end of the input file and by definition there cannot be more than one end of a file (or stream).